# Regular expression to fetch a single id from an array of values in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Regular expression to fetch a single id from an array of values in Jmeter

some responses having multiple values under organization_ids and some responses will have a single value.

The current regular expression gets values as:

```
"org_ids":(\[.*?\])
```

responses:
"org_ids": 1234

some responses:
"org_ids":["12234","133424","234324"]

When multiple values are present in the array need to get only one value.

Response:
"org_ids":["5a7c2","56d0da","5727"]

Please guide which regular expression can give only one value from the above array.

Comment: Do you actually need a value or just to know if there is at least one value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping the entire array. You can group just the first hit:

```
"org_ids":\["([^"]*)".*
```

So the group encloses a single `"`, then the largest possible non `"` match, then a single `"`. Or amending what you have:

```
"org_ids":\["(.*?)".*
```

So a non greedy search of everything between two `"`.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. If don't want to get double quotes in the response like with the given expression I am getting results as "1234" but the value need to get is only 1234. Please suggest.

Comment: @laksh Edited answer - just take `"` out of the `(...)`. Everything in the parentheses is what will be grouped. I suggest you checkout https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html

Answer (score 1):

Your response seems utterly like [JSON](https://www.json.org/) so parsing it using regular expressions is not the best idea, you can easily achieve the same using [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)

1. Add JSON Extractor as a child of the request which returns the above data
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Names of created variables: anything meaningful, i.e. `org_id`
   - JSON Path Expressions: `$..org_ids[*]`
   - Match No: `0`
3. That's it, now you will have a random org_id available as `${org_id}` JMeter Variable.

References:

- [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-examples)
- [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)